# Use #+FILETAGS to set all headings the tag :drill:?

Tags: org-mode, org-tags, org-drill

I'm trying out org-drill and have compiled a small list of headings that I'd like to set the `:drill:` tag to. I also read that one can set a "file-level" tag by using the `#+FILETAGS` method at the top of the org file, like so:

```
#+FILETAGS: drill
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. `M-x org-drill` doesn't pick up any of the headings.

Is this the intended behavior? Is it possible to assign the drill tag at file level, so I don't have to add that to each of the headings in the file?

Comment: What is the value of `org-use-tag-inheritance`? But even if enabled, `org-drill` may be looking for expliciti tags only, not inherited ones.

Comment: I'd open an issue at the [org-drill Gitlab site](https://gitlab.com/phillord/org-drill).

Comment: @NickD `org-use-tag-inheritance` is `t`. I guess `org-drill` requires explicit tags.